# axios interceptor not resending failed request

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios

I am creating this React dashboard app. I'm currently trying to set up an axios interceptor to refresh my access token when I send a request with an expired access token to my backend.

- I have a refresh async action in my slice that makes a get request to my backend with my refresh token cookie. That is being called from my axiosInstance response interceptor.
- After that returns, I set the access token in my store
- Then try to rerun the original failed request

```
return axiosInstance(originalRequest)
```

- The problem is the return statement to rerun the request is not working. when I view my devtools network tab I only see the preflight, failed post request, then refresh request.
- There should be another retry of the first post request after the refresh

Here is my axios code
-Creating my instance and interceptors

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { store } from '../../../app/store';
import { refresh } from '../../auth/authSlice';
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    timeout:5000
})
axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_SCRAPE_URL
axiosInstance.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function(config){    
    const state = store.getState();
    const token = state.auth.accessToken
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    return config
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(resp => resp,async error =>{
    const orginalRequest = error.config
    console.log(error.response);
    
    if(error.response.data === "Invalid Access Token"){
        store.dispatch(refresh({}))
        return axiosInstance(orginalRequest)
    }
})
export default axiosInstance
```

Using the axios Instance (Request that needs to rerun after initial failed request)

```
import axiosInstance from "./protectedScrapeAxios"

export const start = async (pageName, postCount) =>{
    const resp = await axiosInstance.post('/start', {pageName: pageName, postCount: postCount})
    return resp.data

}
```

Comment: 1) You need to add `return Promise.reject(error)` at the end of your interceptor. 2) Shouldn't you be awaiting the `refresh()` dispatch? 3) Have you tried debugging the value of `error.response.data`? Perhaps it's not exactly the string you're expecting

Comment: Why are you using `withCredentials` (aka cookie-based authentication) with bearer tokens? That really doesn't make sense

Comment: Im trying to secure my tokens by saving them as http only and not in local storage. @Phil

Comment: But are you actually wanting to transmit cookies in requests to your API? You're already setting the token into request headers

Comment: Yes, I do, I have two tokens an access and refresh. The refresh is stored in my Redux store and sent with each request, using the request interceptor. The cookie is my refresh token is used in my response interceptor to get a new access token. This all works btw. The problem is I can't get the interceptor to re-run my initial failed request from when I had a bad access token.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. `withCredentials` is vastly misunderstood, especially with cross-origin requests. Back to the **three** points / questions in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533889/axios-interceptor-not-resending-failed-request?noredirect=1#comment129858036_73533889) then...

Comment: 2) I don't think so my because my refresh dispatch is working and I've never done that before.

Comment: But you're immediately retrying the original request without waiting for a new token. Don't you see the problem there?

Comment: 3)And yes the error.response.data is correct is return "Invalid Access Token" I know this because I debugged it and the if statement run

Comment: I see that problem but how would I wait until my new access token is set

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how `refresh` is defined but there's plenty of results when searching for _"redux-toolkit await async dispatch"_